# como crear select dependientes pdo

Tags: php, ajax, pdo

hola amigos actualmente estoy tratando de hacer unos select dependiente, pero no logro que que se me muestren los demas select, si inspecciono el elemento me muestra el valor seleccionado. Mis tablas son las siguientes:

**tabla: empleados**

> id_empleados, nombres, apellidos, telefono, email, direccion

**tabla: cuentas_bancarias**

> id_cuentas_bancarias, id_empleados, numero_cuenta, id_cuentas, id_bancos

**tabla: cuentas**

> id_cuentas, cuentas

**tabla: bancos**

> id_bancos, bancos

**index.php**

```
       <?php

       include 'funciones.php';
       ?>


    `<div class="input-field col s12 m4">
     <select name="id_empleados" id="id_empleados" required>
     <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione un Empleado:</option>
     <?php
      $empleados = muestro_empleados();

      foreach($empleados as $indice => $registro){
      echo "<option value=".$registro['id_empleados'].">".$registro['cedula']." ".$registro['nombres']." ".$registro['apellidos']."</option>";
       }
       ?>
        </select>
        </div>




          <div class="input-field col s12 m4">
          <select  name="id_bancos" id="id_bancos">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Primero seleccion un empleado</option>
          </select>
          </div>



          <div class="input-field col s12 m4">
          <select  name="id_cuentas" id="id_cuentas"/>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Primero seleccion un banco</option>
         </select>
         </div>




        <script>
        $("#id_empleados").on("change", buscar_bancos);
         $("#id_bancos").on("change", buscar_cuentas);

          function buscar_bancos(){
        $("#id_cuentas").html("<option value=''>- primero seleccione un id_bancos -</option>");

       $id_empleados = $("#id_empleados").val();

    if($id_empleados == ""){
  $("#id_bancos").html("<option value=''>- primero seleccione un id_empleados -</option>");
         }
     else {
   $.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  data: {"id_empleados": $id_empleados},
  url:   'funcion2.php',
  type:  'post',
  beforeSend: function(){
    //Lo que se hace antes de enviar el formulario
    },
  success: function(respuesta){
    //lo que se si el destino devuelve algo
    $("#id_bancos").html(respuesta.html);
  },
  error:  function(xhr,err){ 
    alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status+"\n \n responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
  }
   });
   }
   }

   function buscar_cuentas(){
    $id_bancos = $("#id_bancos").val();

    $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    data: {"id_bancos": $id_bancos},
    url:   'funcion2.php',
    type:  'post',
    beforeSend: function(){
  //Lo que se hace antes de enviar el formulario
  },
    success: function(respuesta){
      //lo que se si el destino devuelve algo
      $("#id_cuentas").html(respuesta.html);
     },
    error:  function(xhr,err){ 
  alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status+"\n \n responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
    }
   }); 
   }
  </script>`
```

**funciones.php**

```
    <?php

    function conectaBaseDatos(){
    try{
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $puerto = "3306";
    $basedatos = "sav1";
    $usuario = "root";
    $contrasena = "";
    $conexion = new 
    PDO("mysql:host=$servidor;port=$puerto;dbname=$basedatos",
                        $usuario,
                        $contrasena,
                        array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $conexion;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e){
    die ("No se puede conectar a la base de datos". $e->getMessage());
    }
    }

    function muestro_empleados(){
    $resultado = false;
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM empleados ORDER BY id_empleados";

    $conexion = conectaBaseDatos();
    $sentencia = $conexion->prepare($consulta);

    try {
    if(!$sentencia->execute()){
        print_r($sentencia->errorInfo());
    }
    $resultado = $sentencia->fetchAll();
    //$resultado = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $sentencia->closeCursor();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Error al ejecutar la sentencia: \n";
        print_r($e->getMessage());
    }

    return $resultado;
    }

    function muestro_bancos($id_empleados = ''){
    $resultado = false;
    $consulta = "SELECT
    cuentas_bancarias.id_cuentas_bancarias,
    cuentas_bancarias.id_empleados,
    cuentas_bancarias.numero_cuenta,
    cuentas_bancarias.id_cuentas,
    cuentas_bancarias.id_bancos,
    bancos.id_bancos,
    bancos.bancos
    FROM cuentas_bancarias INNER JOIN bancos ON 
    cuentas_bancarias.id_bancos=bancos.id_bancos";

    if($id_empleados != ''){
    $consulta .= " WHERE id_empleados = :id_empleados";
    }

    $consulta .= " ORDER BY id_cuentas_bancarias";

    $conexion = conectaBaseDatos();
    $sentencia = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
    $sentencia->bindParam('id_empleados',$id_empleados);

    try {
    if(!$sentencia->execute()){
        print_r($sentencia->errorInfo());
    }
    $resultado = $sentencia->fetchAll();
    //$resultado = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $sentencia->closeCursor();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Error al ejecutar la sentencia: \n";
        print_r($e->getMessage());
    }

    return $resultado;
    }

    function muestro_cuentas($id_empleados = ''){
    $resultado = false;
    $consulta = "SELECT
    cuentas_bancarias.id_cuentas_bancarias,
    cuentas_bancarias.id_empleados,
    cuentas_bancarias.numero_cuenta,
    cuentas_bancarias.id_cuentas,
    cuentas_bancarias.id_bancos,
    cuentas.id_cuentas,
    cuentas.cuentas
    FROM cuentas_bancarias INNER JOIN cuentas ON 
    cuentas_bancarias.id_cuentas=cuentas.id_cuentas";

    if($id_empleados != ''){
    $consulta .= " WHERE id_empleados = :id_empleados";
    }

    $consulta .= " ORDER BY id_cuentas_bancarias";

    $conexion = conectaBaseDatos();
    $sentencia = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
    $sentencia->bindParam('id_empleados',$id_empleados);

    try {
    if(!$sentencia->execute()){
        print_r($sentencia->errorInfo());
    }
    $resultado = $sentencia->fetchAll();
    //$resultado = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $sentencia->closeCursor();
    }
     catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Error al ejecutar la sentencia: \n";
        print_r($e->getMessage());
     }

     return $resultado;
     }


     ?>
```

**funcion2.php**

```
<?php
 require_once("funciones.php");

 if(isset($_POST['id_empleados'])){

$cuentas_bancarias = muestro_bancos($_POST['id_empleados']);

$html = "<option value=''>- Seleccione un bancos -</option>";
foreach($cuentas_bancarias as $indice => $registro){
    $html .= "<option value='".$registro['id_empleados']."'>".$registro['bancos']."</option>";
}

$respuesta = array("html"=>$html);
echo json_encode($respuesta);
 }

 if(isset($_POST['id_bancos'])){

$cuentas_bancarias= muestro_cuentas($_POST['id_bancos']);

$html = "<option value=''>- Seleccione una cuenta -</option>";
foreach($cuentas_bancarias as $indice => $registro){
    $html .= "<option value='".$registro['id_empleados']."'>".$registro['cuentas']."</option>";
}

$respuesta = array("html"=>$html);
echo json_encode($respuesta);
}

?>
```

ahora lo que quiero lograr es: en el select uno se cargan los datos personales del empleado, luego cuando se selecciones el empleado se debe cargar en el segundo select que bancos tiene registrado ese empleado, luego en el tercer select se cargaría el tipo de cuenta: si es ahorro o corriente y por ultimo el numero de cuenta del empleado.

Comment: Para lograr lo que quieres es necesario que comiences a utilizar Ajax, así podrás retornar la información en base a tus select.

Comment: ok gracias amigos por sus respuestas tendrán un ejemplo a la mano o link para guiarme

Comment: Puedes mirar este ejemplo, incluye el código: https://blog.elporfirio.com/como-hacer-un-combo-select-option-dinamico/  lo puedes adaptar a lo que ya tienes.

Comment: @yoclens lo ideal es usar **AJAX**, pero antes de nada, si es un proyecto nuevo te recomiendo mirar algún framework **Modelo-Vista-Controlador**  tipo **Laravel** o **CodeIgniter** . Lo agradecerás en el presente...

Comment: @yoclens no recomiendo que si es nuevo mire un framework, que eso lo haga luego que ya este mas o menos empapado en el lenguaje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

así fue como lo solucione:

```
<script>
$("#id_empleados").on("change", buscar_bancos);
$("#id_bancos").on("change", buscar_cuentas);
$("#id_cuentas").on("change", buscar_numero_cuentas);

 function buscar_bancos(){
 $("#id_numero_cuentas").html("<option value=''>Primero Seleccione una 
 Cuenta</option>");

 $id_empleados = $("#id_empleados").val();

 if($id_empleados == ""){
  $("#id_bancos").html("<option value=''>Primero Seleccione una 
 Empleado</option>");
 }
  else {
   $.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  data: {"id_empleados": $id_empleados},
  url:   '../conexion/funciones2.php',
  type:  'POST',
  beforeSend: function(){
    //Lo que se hace antes de enviar el formulario
    },
  success: function(respuesta){
    //lo que se si el destino devuelve algo
    $("#id_bancos").html(respuesta.html);
  },
  error:  function(xhr,err){ 
    alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status+"\n \n 
  responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
  }
  });
  }
  }

  function buscar_cuentas(){
  $id_bancos = $("#id_bancos").val();

  $.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
data: {"id_bancos": $id_bancos},
url:   '../conexion/funciones2.php',
    type:  'POST',
beforeSend: function(){
  //Lo que se hace antes de enviar el formulario
  },
    success: function(respuesta){
  //lo que se si el destino devuelve algo
  $("#id_cuentas").html(respuesta.html);
},
error:  function(xhr,err){ 
  alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status+"\n \n responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
}
 }); 
}

 function buscar_numero_cuentas(){
 $id_cuentas = $("#id_cuentas").val();

 $.ajax({
dataType: "json",
data: {"id_cuentas": $id_cuentas},
url:   '../conexion/funciones2.php',
    type:  'POST',
beforeSend: function(){
  //Lo que se hace antes de enviar el formulario
  },
    success: function(respuesta){
  //lo que se si el destino devuelve algo
  $("#id_numero_cuentas").html(respuesta.html);
},
error:  function(xhr,err){ 
  alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status+"\n \n 
responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
}
}); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Cuántos select dependientes hiciste? Es que yo necesito hacer 3 y no puedo.